# Tizen wearable web application with Angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, angular7, tizen, tizen-web-app

I’m trying to create a Tizen wearable web application using Angular 7.

The idea is to realize a simple angular app and then put the build files (obtained with ng build --prod command) inside a Tizen Studio base project. This way I can build to a wearable device.

Everything seems to work properly but now I’m facing a couple of problems:

1. I need to use a code snippet like the following inside an angular component but ‘**tizen**’ is not found. I figure I have to import tizen library somehow but I’ve no idea how to proceed (even where to find this library).

   `tizen.application.getCurrentApplication().exit();`
2. I would like to use TAU (Tizen Advanced UI) directly inside angular code but I’m not able to import the library. I’m looking for some npm package or another way to import and use it.

Any suggestion is well accepted.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can use `(<any>window).tizen.application...` or even better, extend `Window` interface with `tizen` object.
2. TAU library is based on jQuery mobile - it is not designed to work with Angular. These frameworks are completely different.

Answer (score 0):

The comment above, worked for me.

I implemented on the first page of my app an event to listen the return button of the remote (keyCode = 10009) and to close the application, i implemented the code above.

```
import {Component, HostListener, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
   selector: 'app-mycomponent',
   templateUrl: './my.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./my.component.scss'],
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
   static KEYCODE_RETURN_TIZEN = 10009;
  @HostListener('window:keydown', ['$event']) onClick(event: KeyboardEvent) {
     if ([MyComponent.KEYCODE_RETURN_TIZEN].includes(event.keyCode)) {
     // Implement any confirm component
     (window as any).tizen.application.getCurrentApplication().exit();
    }
  }
}
```